# React-Hooks: Fetching data results into empty 'hits' array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch data with React Hooks. It all seems to work but the `hits` array is empty even though the data is fetched correctly.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default function Dashboard(props) {
  var classes = useStyles();
  var theme = useTheme();

  // local
  var [mainChartState, setMainChartState] = useState("monthly");

  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
  const url = my_url;
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        url,
      );
      setData(result.data);
      console.log(result.data);
      console.log(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

 return (

  <Grid item xs={12}>
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <MUIDataTable
      title="Analyzed DAOs"
      data={data.hits}
      columns={["Name", "Members", "Proposals", "Voters"]}
      options={{
        filterType: "checkbox",
      }}
    />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Grid>
 )
}
```

When printing out the `result.data`, I get an array with 5 objects (as it should be) but when printing out the `data.hits` the result is am empty array, and the table shows zero rows.

What am I missing? Probably a lifecycle issue, but how do I fix it?

Comment: `setData` is asynchronous, so `setData(result.data)` and then `console.log(data)` will show you the "old" state. You'll get the new/updated state when the component re-renders after updating the state. Also, you're making a mistake as described in the answer below.

Comment: @goto1 console.log(data) actually prints the data. But for some reason it doesn't get to the component. I'm using the code here, https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data pretty much as is. Something else is going on.

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(data.hits)` right before the `return` statement and after the `useEffect` hook gets called and the `fetchData` completes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the OP. Looks like for the code, as written in my question, to work, my data needs to be wrapped with a bit of `json`.

My data, as it comes from the server, is a `json array`. To make it work I did the following:

```
var jsonData = {};
jsonData.hits = result.data;
setData(jsonData);
```

That's it. Now it all works. It's a workaround and there's probably a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `setData({ hits: [result.data] })` will allow your result to be assigned to `data.hits`.

`setData` will completely override any default or current value for `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works as expected, I guess you just need to keep the `MUIDataTable` **columns** matches the properties and the data structure that returned from your API.

Assume your returned data look like this:

```js
const data = [
 { 
   name: "Joe James", 
   company: "Test Corp", 
   city: "Yonkers", 
   state: "NY"
   ...
 },
 // more objects
];
```

You will need to set your columns like this:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    name: "name", // This should match the data property
    label: "Name", // Label will be shown
    options: {...}
  },
  {
    name: "company",
    label: "Company",
    options: {...}
  }, 
  {
    // More columns for `city` and `state` etc...
  }
```

Please follow this [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muidatatables-custom-toolbar-9jfi3) example.

Comment: does the actual data need to have a `{"hits":` in the `json` before the array? Or is the name `hits` part of the framework?

Comment: Nah, it's just a preference. actually you will just need to follow your returned data structure.

Comment: Aside note: actually this not a good way to fetch your API, usually you'll need to set a `state` flag to check if the data is ready yet plus a error handling to debug your code in case something went wrong. it's all explained in the [url](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) you posted earlier.

Comment: Looks like it does needs the `hits` in the json. I'll answer my own question. But thanks for the playground, it was easy to experiment there.